How to set Notes for edited cells from range A:H in Google Apps script? I use chat GPT to help but the intersects function doesn't work. I'm a newbie
I am new to Sheets app script, and tried to find how to debug. but could not get. Here is by onEdit event function. If I click the 'Debug'(Debug the selected function) menu, the debugging works. but the parameter e is not defined, since the OnEdit function is not called from sheets by cell edit.
I am clueless how to debug the onEdit function, by editing a cell ?
I want to set notes for cells that I edit to the extent I need.
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Test');
  if (!sheet) return; 
  var range = e.range;
  var monitoredRange = sheet.getRange('A1:B10');

  if (monitoredRange.intersects(range)) {
    if (range.getValue() !== "") {
      range.setNote('Edited on: ' + new Date());
    } else 
      range.clearNote();
    }
  }
}


Debug onEdit function
Here are different ways you can debug your code that contains an onEdit() function, first is to examine the execution logs to see the error that the compiler runs into, you can access Google Apps Script's execution logs by following the steps below:
Open execution log
From the left side of Google apps script editor's home page, click the 'executions' button(see image below):

View execution log item:
From the execution logs' page, you will see the error log that the code encountered,(the execution log of the latest run will be at the top), you will then be able to see the error that your code encountered(note: the error log from the image below is associated to your given code)

Use toast()
Another way to debug your onEdit() function is to use toast method which you can use to display custom message or values of certain variables:
See code below(which uses toast):

My code passes just a simple string message to the toast method but you can also pass a variable in it and the toast in the image shows after I edit a cell from range A1:B10.
References: Toast(),
